# Why do the tangent holes (like in pitot-static tube) feel the static pressure?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics

Why do the tangent holes (like in pitot-static tube) feel the static pressure although the static pressure is in the direction of the velocity of the streamlines not normal to the surface of the hole[image]

Comment: BTW, on airplanes the static ports are sometimes on an angled surface protruding from the body, designed to counteract the forces of the air traveling around the various curves of the airplane body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some confusion:

[Stagnation Pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stagnation_pressure) is likely what you are thinking of - it is in the direction of fluid velocity, and includes the [dynamic pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_pressure) + the [static pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_pressure#Static_pressure_in_fluid_dynamics).  The distinction is important.

**Stagnation pressure** is a measure of the energy in the system.  You can't measure stagnation pressure with a tangent hole.  You use a [pitot tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitot_tube) to measure that.

**Static pressure** is like water pressure from your garden hose, when you plug up the end with your thumb.  No water is flowing, but it pushes back with a lot of pressure.  The tangential hole, *especially when the diameter is much smaller than the ducting you are measuring*, is usually behind a [boundary layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_layer).  It can't measure any dynamic pressure, so it only measures the static pressure.

**Dynamic pressure** is energy due to the air moving.  It is measured by taking the difference between the **stagnation pressure** and the **static pressure**.  It uses a device exactly like the one you depict here, measuring the difference between the two pressures with a tangential hole and a pitot tube.

If you want more information, or just want help with design or principles of any of these kind of measurement devices, [SE.Engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/) can also help.

Comment: I know these details but what i ask about is how the tangential hole measures the static pressure. how it feels that static pressure although it is tangential and no force on it from that static pressure !

Comment: It should feel the static pressure.  If you put your thumb over the top of the garden hose, the hose would push on your thumb, even though it has no flow.  That's static pressure.  The air in you system is also under some small amount of static pressure - it's not much but it's there.

Comment: that is correct.I understood it. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, according to John Denker at [*av8n.com*](http://www.av8n.com/how/htm/airfoils.html#sec-static-stagnation) is that the decrease in static pressure due to velocity is, to a first approximation, $1/2\rho v^2$ and $v$ is small compared to the speed of sound.
It's small enough to neglect.
As he says:

> As you increase your airspeed, the stagnation pressure goes up, but
>   the static pressure does not.

Answer (score 0):

Pressure is isotopic (it acts equally in all directions) so it doesn't matter how the static pressure hole is oriented (it just happens that a hole in the tube sidewall is convenient and hence is tangential to the flow). Nevertheless the pitot tube *must* face into the flow in order to bring it to rest.

Comment: but when we proved the momentum equation we considered that the static pressure affects only on two faces of the fluid element and neglected the vertical pressure from the gravity      ![Valid XHTML](http://s9.postimg.org/pal98fo67/static.png).

Answer (score 0):

It's because the Prandtl condition is valid. The pressure on the streamline is the same as the pressure at the hole,
$$\frac{\mathrm dp}{\mathrm dy}=0$$